# Error importing data to a model in Django

Tags: python, django, unicode

I´m trying to import data from a csv file to a Django model. I´m using the manage.py shell for it with the following code:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import os
>>> path =  "C:\\Users\Lia Love\Downloads" 
>>> os.chdir(path) 
>>> from catalog.models import ProductosBase
>>> with open('FarmaciasGob.csv') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...             p = Country(country=row['Country'], continent=row['Continent'])
...             p.save()
...
>>>
>>> exit()
```

I get the following error message at a given point of the dataset:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: "charmap" codec can´t decode byte 0x81 in position 7823: character maps to (undefined)
```

For what I could find, it seems to be a problem with the "latin" encoding of the csv file.

Inspecting the csv, I don´t see nothing special about the specific row where it get´s the error. I´m able to import about 2200 rows before this one, all with latin characters.

Any clues?

Comment: This is an issue with encoding are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: Using Python 3.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are in python3, this is an issue of the character encoding of your file.  Most likely, the encoding is 'utf-8', but it could also be 'utf-16', 'utf-16le', 'cp1252', or 'cp437', all of which are also commonly used.  In python3, you can specify the encoding of the file on the `open`:

```
with open('FarmaciasGob.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
```

Comment: It worked perfectly with encoding="latin-1". Thanks @2ps